# Non visual components without forms

Tags: delphi, vcl

i started creating application only using dpr file in delphi 2009 , i think all basic things work i use system ,sysutils and more....  but now i want to use timer and some other non-visual components (some basic indy components to use internet) is there any ways to do this
i do not bother using units (but not forms)

Comment: can we also use any non visual componets like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put non-visual components on a Data Module.

I use that a lot because you still have the design-time benefits (properties and events in the object inspector, logical placement in your designer).

--jeroen

Answer (score 1):

You can create any component by calling its constructor and passing **nil** as the owner.  You won't need a parent form if you manage it yourself.  But for some things, you will still need a project that uses forms, even if you're not placing your component on one.  For TTimer, for example, you have to be running a VCL Forms app because it depends on `Application` and its message loop to make the timer work.

Comment: You do not need a VCL Forms app in order to use TTimer. As long as there is a message loop that receives and dispatches WM_TIMER messages for the thread context that TTimer runs in, it will work fine.  You can call the Win32 API Get/PeekMessage() and DispatchMessage() functions directly for that.